# Make incoming call silent

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to make android ringer silent on receive of a call from certain number. I know that we can do something like below-

```
AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

But I dont want to permanenlty change ringer mode. I just want to make it silent temporarily e.g. when we have an incoming call in android, and we press side buttons on the phone, it gets silent for that call.

One way is to store the old mode, change mode on call and then set it back after the current call. But I think there should be a better way of doing this.

How to achieve this?